# Process to sponsor child - Canada

Tags: immigration, canadian-citizens, india

Parents have Canadian PR status.

My spouse is planning to deliver baby in India.

---

Do I need to sponsor new baby for moving baby to Canada?

What is the process to sponsor?

Does baby achieve PR status on sponsorship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canada has an extensive [guide](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5525ETOC.asp) explaining the process, along with an even more detailed [guide](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5289ETOC.asp).

> Do I need to sponsor new baby for moving baby to Canada?

Yes, it appears that you do.

> What is the process to sponsor?

The shorter guide's outline lists the following sections:

> Before you start
>   Get your application package
>   Fill out your forms
>   Gather your documents
>   Check for common mistakes
>   Pay your fees
>   Submit your application
>   What to expect after you submit the application
>   Appendix A - Key definitions
>   Appendix B - Photo specifications
>   Appendix C – "X" in the sex field on an immigration document

You also ask

> Does baby achieve PR status on sponsorship?

If the sponsorship application is successful, the baby will receive a permanent resident visa.  I believe the baby needs to travel to Canada before the visa expires in order to become a permanent resident, but I am not certain of that.